# Apache Solr search index problem

Tags: drupal-6, solr, drupal-search

I have installed Apache Solr and run 2 times manually cron but I have a problem that 0% was sent to server:

```
The search index is generated by running cron. 0% of the site content has been sent to the server. There are 2884 items left to send.

Using schema.xml version: drupal-1.1
The server has a 2 min. delay before updates are processed.

Number of documents in index: 220

Number of pending deletions: 0
```

All messages seems to be ok:

```
* Apache Solr: Your site has contacted the Apache Solr server.
* Apache Solr PHP Client Library: Correct version "Revision: 22".
```

I replaced solrconfig.xml and schema.xml in /solr/example/solr/conf with those from Apache Solr Drupal module.

Could somebody give me advice, what should I check?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed the same problem. The problem was with sites/default/files folder and folder permissions.

Try to set 775 for files/ folder and etc, I guess on /admin/reports/status you'll see lots of warnings for misconfigured perms.

After resolving this stuff, solr indexed content properly.